# Vue - how to set attribute on v-btn when clicked and remove on response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

There are multiple `Realestate` components on the page. There is a button `publish` inside this component and there is a function `VM.webflowPublishRealestate(id)`

Inside the component, there is this btn:

```
            <v-btn :ref="'webflow_publish_btn_'+realestate.id" @click="$emit('webflow-publish',realestate.id)" color="green">Publikovať aktuálnu verziu</v-btn>
```

and this is how the component is used:

```
 <v-col :key="realestate.id" cols="12" v-for="realestate in getPublishedRealestates()" class="pa-3" md="6"
                       lg="4" sm="12">

                    <realestate_card :realestate="realestate"
                                     @duplicate-realestate-icon-clicked="duplicateRealestateIconClicked(realestate)"
                                     @delete-realestate-icon-clicked="deleteRealestateIconClicked(realestate)"
                                     @update-realestate-icon-clicked="updateRealestateIconClicked(realestate)"
                                     @patch-realestate="patchRealestate($event[0],$event[1],$event[2])"
                                     @webflow-publish="webflowPublishRealestate($event)"
                    ></realestate_card>


                </v-col>
```

My idea was to add (and after axios - remove) `loading` attribute to the button inside the method `webflowPublishRealestate` but I can't access the reference since it is not created.

Do you know another way how to do that? I can't reference the button with static string since there is a loop of these components.

This is my method:

```
webflowPublishRealestate(id) {
            var url = this.URLS.REALESTATE_WEBFLOW_PUBLISH.replace('0', id);
            var self = this;
            this.$refs['webflow_publish_btn_' + id].loading = true;
            axios.post(url).then(response => {
                alertRealestateWebflowPublished();
            }).catch(error => {

            }).finally(() => {
                self.$refs['webflow_publish_btn_' + id].loading = true;
            })
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `refs` for this.

You can use reactive properties to achieve this.

Should declare a `isLoading` variable inside your `realEstates` objects and add this to `data` so it's reactive.

Then you can use it directly on the button

`<v-btn :ref="'webflow_publish_btn_'+realestate.id" @click="$emit('webflow-publish',realestate.id)" color="green" :loading="realEstates[id].loading">Publikovať aktuálnu verziu</v-btn>`

Notice the `:` before `loading`.

And then update the value from your axios call.

`realEstates[id].loading = true`